# Auto shutdown file in startup

Tags: windows

I have a batch file with name hack.bat with content "shutdown /s /t 0"
when I press this my system shutdown automatically

I have placed this file in a startup folder 
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"

This action makes the file Hack.bat to execute on start of windows.
when ever I login into my account this hack.bat is running and system is shutting down.

please help me to resolve this problem.!!!!!

Comment: Hold down the shift key while booting AND logging in. If that doesn't work press F8 repeatedly while powering on and choose Safe Mode.

Comment: Another option would be to start the PC but not log in. If it can be accessed on the network, connect to the administrative share `\\ip-of-computer\c$` and navigate to the folder containing the file, delete the file, then log in again.

Comment: Take a look on the internet for "repair your computer", this site isn't the correct place for non programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to boot into safe mode to move or remove the file, the method depends on which version of windows you are currently using.

Windows XP and 7:

Press F8 immediately after your BIOS screen goes away (on some PCs the dead givaway is your screen flashing) then choose safe mode from there. after your computer boots find and move or delete the offending batch file from *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp*.

Windows 8, 8.1, and 10:

Boot your install disk, chose "Repair your computer" then "Troubleshoot" "Startup Settings" and click "Restart". this will restart your computer into a new menu, choose the option that says "Enable Safe Mode" (usually #4) from there find and move or delete the offending batch file from *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp*.